# Project is linked but not exporting data

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have integrated BigQuery to my firebase project. But the product card of BigQuery there is showing "Project is linked but not exporting data".

I am able to see the events, audiences and aggregated data in my firebase console UI. But I am not sure how do I make the same data exported to BigQuery.

I am using **BigQuery Sandbox**

[image]

It has been more than 24 hours now since I've integrated BigQuery to my project. 
Please help me, I am stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

*I was able to solve this problem with a small hack that I figured out unintentionally.*

**First thing,** you will never be able to export your events to BigQuery if your account has only web projects enabled.

We will have to create a dummy ios or android project in our firebase account. That's it, literally. This is the only **additional** step we need to take in order to view our events in firebase.

Here is the complete series of steps I took which led the firebase events pushed to BigQuery:

1. Create a web project in firebase.
2. Create an ios/android project in the same firebase account.
3. Enable BigQuery to the account.
4. Used Web project's configuration in web application.
5. Wait for at least 24 hours to see the events in the BigQuery. Tables will be created automatically. You don't have to do anything.

```
 var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxx"
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Official answer from support:

Option 1:
Add firebase-measurement@system.gserviceaccount.com as an Editor on the project from the GCP console.
Wait overnight, and confirm if the export is completed the next day.

Option 2:
Add a (dummy) mobile app.
Unlink, then link Firebase and BigQuery again. Exports should be available 24 hours after linking.

I tried Option 1 and it worked. Option 2 seems weird and I didn't wanted to use it.

Comment: Unlinking and linking big-query again to the project solved the problem for me immediately without having to wait after re-linking

Answer (score 1):

Generally this error comes up when either no apps are toggled on for the [linked](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765) Firebase project [integrations](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765#manage) or the certain applications actually don't export any events, thus the data transfer will not be performed and particular Bigquery dataset would not be created.

According to the presented screenshot, I see that you have registered none of the apps within the current Firebase project that can be considered as for [Google analytics](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9289399?hl=en&ref_topic=6317497) export.

Answer (score 1):

For the export to work, you need to create app in the project. The app doesn't have to do anything, nor do you have to verify it or validate it, it just needs to exist.
You can fill the details of a dummy app and it should work.

The reason for this is that the BigQuery export was created before the web stream concept was introduced with Google Analytics: App + Web, and in its current state, having just a web stream will not enable the export.

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/enable-bigquery-export-google-analytics-app-web/

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem and this is the first thread I've found to address it specifically.

My project has an app and the project is linked to bigQuery (according to Firebase Project Settings/Integrations)

I've checked "Include web apps and streams in export"

But after 2 days it still says:
"Dataset not created"  and "Apps exporting 0 of 0 apps"

At a complete loss. If anyone has any insight, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a corner case that generates this error. If you linked BigQuery with your Web app, and then changed the app name of your Web app, then the integration will show this error and "0 of 0 apps"...

So I have to change the Web app's name back to the original one.